# how to link a binary vs a symlink and not an actual library?

Tags: linker, meson-build

I have a meson file that declares a dependency:

`meson.get_compiler('cpp').find_library('name'),`

where `name` can be found in:

1. /usr/lib/libname.so -> /usr/lib/libname.so.1.2.3
2. /usr/lib/libname.so.1.2.3

I want meson to link vs. the symlink alone - so when running the executable on another machine, with another version of `libname` -it would still work, and not give me:

can't find libname.so.1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I created dependency for my test application with:

```
dep = meson.get_compiler('c').find_library('ssh')
```

The executable points to

```
ldd ./build/test_proj | grep libssh
libssh.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 (0x00007f3d668b8000)
```

And, surely, this is a symbolic link with major number pointing

```
$ ls -alt /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Aug 29 00:13 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Aug 18  2021 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4 -> libssh.so.4.8.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 445976 Aug 18  2021 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4
```

Thus, it's major number that is crucial and decides on selection of library, not minor numbers.

I made an experiment: removed *libssh.so.4* and linker cache (/etc/ld.so.cache) to force your situation so I have only:

```
$ ls -alt /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Aug 29 00:13 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 445976 Aug 18  2021 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.4
```

In this case linkage failed:

```
ninja: Entering directory `build'                                                                   
[2/2] Linking target test_proj
...
    libssh.so.4 => not found
```

So, I think you're missing *libssh.so.4* link and major number is a must since it guarantees API conformance.